# Добавление выбранной пользователем ватермарки на выбранную им же картинку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть проста
В picturebox загружается картинка,  потом по нажатию кнопки добавляется ватермарка
НО! Сейчас добавляется только указанная в пути в коде картинка и ватермарка, а надо чтобы пользователь сам мог выбирать нужную ему картинку и ватермарку и все это с минимальными изменениями кода
Собственно, код

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlipToFlip
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     //Открываем картинку
        {
            Bitmap image; //Bitmap для открываемого изображения
            {
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    textbox.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                }
            }

            {
                try
                {
                    image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);   //Bitmap для открываемой картинки

                    pictureBox1.Size = image.Size;    //Картинка подгоняется под размер picturebox
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                }
                catch
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Невозможно открыть выбранный файл",
                    "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);    //Если это НЕ картинка
                }
            }

        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    //Сохранение повернутой картинки
        {
            Bitmap pngSave = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.DefaultExt = "png";
            sfd.Filter = "Image files (*.png;*jpg;*gif)|*.png; *jpg; *gif;|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

                pngSave.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
        }



        private void watermark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (Image watermarkImage = image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\14829270527610.png"))
            using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            using (TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
            {
                int x = (image.Width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2);
                int y = (image.Height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);
                watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);
                imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Делайте.

Comment: Т.е. как загрузить картинку в `pictureBox` через `OpenFileDialog` вы разобрались, а с аналогичным действием для ватермарки - нет?